# make OpenVPN Run as service but not auto-connect on Windows

Tags: windows, openvpn

OpenVPN is configured to run as service. It starts up successfully and auto connect. But I have more than 10 configuration files in config/, and I don't know which configuration OpenVPN uses to connect, and I find no way to disconnect, reconnect or switch connection.
What I want is, having OpenVPN run as service in background (but not auto-connecting), I use OpenVPN GUI to start a connection when logging on as standard account.
Any idea? Thanks you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use [OpenVPN MI GUI](http://openvpn-mi-gui.inside-security.de/). You need to edit the config files to allow for it to manage tunnels started as a service, and then it works from a standard account. I believe management-hold is the option in the config file to make it not auto-connect on startup.

Comment: `management-hold` is the correct option. You should close the MI GUI before editing the file and I think also the service requires a restart to pick up and changes in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

The service Mode is designed for Server mode. If you start the service (or it is started automatically) all ovpn files will connect.
You can also use this feature on a client when you always want to connect to the same destination(s). But if you want to choose the connection, you should use the GUI. Is there any advantage when running a service?

Answer (score 0):

When you start the service OpenVPN will use all of the configs to connect at the same time.

> When OpenVPN runs as a service it will start a separate OpenVPN process for each configuration file it finds in the \Program Files\OpenVPN\config directory and will output a logfile of the same name to the \Program Files\OpenVPN\log directory.

https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill 